# Checking input values to methods to reduce the number of computations

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, wxpython

I have a number of methods that are independent of each other but are needed collectively to compute an output. Thus, when a variable in any of the methods changes all the methods are called in the computation which is slow and expensive. Here is a quick pesudo-code of what I have:

```
# o represents an origin variable
# valueA represents a variable which can change
def a (o, valueA): 
    # calculations
    return resultA

def b (o, valueB):
    # calculations
    return resultA

def c (o, valueC1, valueC2):
    # calculations
    return resultA

def compute (A, B, C1, C2):
    one = self.a(o, A)
    two = self.b(one,B)
    three = self.c(two, C1, C2)
    return img
```

For example when the value of C1 changes, when calling `compute` all the methods are calculated despite `a` & `b` having no change. What I would like is some way of checking which of the values of `A,B,C1,C2` have changed between each call to `compute`.

I have considered defining a list of the values then on the next call comparing it to the new values being pass to `compute`. Eg; 1st call: `list=[1,2,3,4]` on 2nd call `list=[1,3,4,5]` so `b` & `c` need calculating but `a` is the same. However, I am unsure as to how to go from the comparison to defining which method to call?

Some background on my particular application in case it is of use. I have a wxPython window with sliders that determine values for image processing and an image is drawn on each change of these sliders.

What is the best way to compare each call to `compute` and remove these wasted repeated computations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i have to solve this, I would use a Dictionary, where the key is the valueX (or a list of it if have more than one, in your example C) and the value should be the result of the function.

So, you should have something like that:

```
{ valueA: resultA, valueB: resultB, [valueC1, valueC2]: resultC }
```

To do that, in the functions you will have to add it:

```
def a(o, valueA):
    [calcs]
    dic[valueA] = resultA
    return resultA
[...]
def c(o, valueC1, valueC2)
    [calcs]
    dic[[valueC1, valueC2]] = resultC
    return resultC
```

And, in the function that computes, you can try to get the value for the parameters and if not get the value, calculate it

```
def compute (A, B, C1, C2):
    one = dic.get(A) if dic.get(A) else self.a(o, A)
    two = dic.get(B) if dic.get(B) else self.b(one,B)
    three = dic.get([C1,C2]) if dic.get([C1,C1]) else self.c(two, C1, C2)
    return img
```

P.D: this is the "crude" implementation of memoize functions that @holdenweb pointed in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider making the methods [`memoizing functions`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) that use a dict to look up the results of previously stored computations (probably best in the class namespace to allow memoizing to optimize across all instances).

The memory requirements could be quite severe, however, if the methods are called with many arguments, in which case you might want to adopt a ["publish and subscribe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern to try and make your computation more "systolic" (driven by changes in the data, loosely).

That' a couple of approaches. I'm sure SO will think of more.